# XlsxWriter, finding rows in a worksheet that contain a specific text and apply formatting to those rows only

Tags: python, excel, loops, xlsxwriter

I am hoping someone can help me.  I have written a dataframe to a worksheet using XlsxWriter, and within the worksheets are rows that contain subtotals.
Example:

```
A      |B           |C   |D
---------------------------
area1  |subarea1    |2   |4
       |subarea2    |1   |3
       |subtotal1|  |3   |7
area2  |subarea1    |3   |3
       |subarea2    |1   |5
       |subtotal2|  |4   |8
...
```

I would like to identify the subtotal rows and apply formatting to just those rows. I have looked through other similar questions but not found something that will work so far. I can already apply formatting to headers, footers, columns and ranges dynamically, but can't figure out how to identify the rows.
I am guessing it would be something like this:

```
for row in worksheet.rows:
    if 'subtotal' in row:
        worksheet.conditional_format(
                                       ('B' + row +':' + 'L' + row),
                                        ....
```

so far the closest I have been able to come gives me the error message

```
> TypeError: 'Worksheet' object is not iterable
```

Is this even possible?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: It isn't possible with query the data you write using XlsxWriter. You will need to work out the location of the rows from the dataframe using `shape()` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks now I know I was going in the wrong direction.  I appreciate the assistance.